# Django object.filter is not loading all results

Tags: python, mysql, django

I am using Django 1.10.4 and MySQL 5.7.

So, I have following models:

```
class Image(models.Model):
    request = models.ForeignKey(Request, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    customID = models.CharField(max_length=128, null=True)
    status = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    row = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    column = models.IntegerField(default=0)

class Request(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128, null=True)
```

Then I am loading all Image objects for some Request (this can run in a few threads):

```
images = models.Image.objects.filter(request_id=req_id).order_by('column', 'row')
```

The problem is, I am not always getting correct set of Image objects. Sometimes it loads them all, sometimes it kinda stops in the middle of loading. What I mean is that I get for example 4 out of 10, or 11 out of 12 Image objects. The row-column pair is always uniqe for Image in single Request, but when this problem occurs, the last loaded Image object have row and column = 0 (when the correct ones, saved in DB are for example 1, 8). How is this possible? And why I don't get any exceptions or errors?

Comment: "this can run in a few threads" sounds like a possible issue to me... what are the other threads doing and why are you using threading at all?

Comment: I already tried using threading.Lock but with little sucess. After loading whole set of images I'm starting c++ app on actual png files files described in that model. It needs ~ 10 minutes to finish, and to handle all incoming images I can't just launch that one at a time.

Comment: Have you checked in your database that the images are really there? Have you tried running your view in a transaction?

Comment: Yes, it's all in the database. The tricky part is, that if another thread tries to access the same request after previous one failed, it usually works (or rarely fail after loading different number of images than the first thread). Im running all database related stuff using "transaction.atomic", I even tried using mysql lock, still no success.

Comment: It sounds like you need to use something like celery to manage the c++ task separately

Comment: I would like to keep this system as simple as possible. If I can find the reason why it fails I'm pretty sure I can handle it without using celery. I will keep that one as the last resort.

Comment: @ljon in my experience, managing threads can get very messy esp. when need to scale up. Celery is cumbersome but the way to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem surprisingly wasn't directly connected to threads. Last few weeks images sending to system grew in number and size (about 10 times in case of size) and I did not take this into account. I tried to load request images too fast in some cases, when all images weren't saved yet. Well, I will not make the same mistake twice.